# Upper shower flange

Tags: shower

I installed a shower flange and used a kerdi membrane on top of that. I did a water test and nothing leaked.

After installing the upper part of the flange I poured some water around the drain to see what the water would do. The little water I poured did not go down the drain. It seems to me the membrane could be blocking the channels that are on the upper flange and not letting the water thru, or is this normal?

Comment: This is hard to decipher without pics.  You may need a weep guide after the Kerdi and before the top of the flange.   Or you may be expecting the water to run down quickly when the channels are only there for water that seeps past the finished floor and allows it to weep through to the drain.

Comment: Could be a slope issue, could be just surface tension.  As suggested, get some (good) pics.